# Parse error iOS [unrecognized selector sent to instance]

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, ios9

I have an app saving images to parse, it consists of a collection view in the first VC and a detail view controller where you add a picture via UIImagePickerController. I've worked with parse a bit in Objective-C before, but keep getting this error

```
[PFObject setPhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa15ac8f1c0
```

I have a parse class in the project with the properties, I know there is a different way but I've usually done it like this and had no problems.

Parse class header file

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface Picture : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Caption;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Likes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Photo;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "Picture.h"

static NSString * const ClassName = @"Picture";

@implementation Picture

@dynamic Caption;
@dynamic Likes;
@dynamic Photo;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {

return ClassName;

}

@end
```

Here is where I save the image

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add caption" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

    textField.placeholder = @"title";

}];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    NSArray *textFields = [alertController textFields];

    NSString *nameString = ((UITextField *)textFields[0]).text;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.chosenImage);

//        PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Picture"];

    Picture *picture = [Picture object];

    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithData:imageData];


    [picture saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (succeeded) {

            picture.Photo = file;
            picture.Caption = nameString;

            [picture saveInBackground];
            [picture pinInBackground]; 

            UIAlertController *successAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Photo Saved!" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [successAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

            [self presentViewController:successAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        else {

            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }

    }];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay!" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil]];

    //save to parse here

}]];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

//image picker delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

self.chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = self.chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I thought at first it could be the size of the image but when I comment that part out and just try to save the caption I get the same error but with "setCaption" rather than "setPhoto"

Update: The objects have saved to parse but there is no data in the column, the keys (properties) are spelled right and everything too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the dynamically generated setters are not getting created on your custom PFObject.

The problem may be your choice of case on your properties. The convention as defined by Apple is to start a property with a lowercase letter and have it be camel case thereafter. You should change the case to lowercase, as that may be causing a conflict with the creation of the getters.

You already have

```
PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Picture"];
```

and I'm guessing that your code did not work with that.

The other thing I can suggest is to move

```
picture.Photo = file;
picture.Caption = nameString;
```

out of the block and put it after `PFFile *file = [PFFile...` and delete

```
[picture saveInBackground];
```

as you appear to be saving your picture object twice. From your description that corresponds to the empty record that you are getting in Parse. Therefore, that save is being successfully performed. It is the second save that is failing.

Also, try adding

```
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

to your implementation (.m) file as that is where the class method for `object` is defined.

Comment: That didn't work. This is really odd though, I have another project where this works fine. You think it's an iOS 9 thing?

Comment: I'm not sure. I suspect it has something to do with your Parse installation such as it being corrupted in some way. Did you install it using CocoaPods? Or another method?

Comment: No, I just dragged the frameworks in from the quick start part of the parse website then added the other manually.

Comment: To isolate the problem, I suggest making a new project with a fresh install of the necessary libraries. Then test your code in the new project.

Comment: Yea I could do that, I'm just really curious as to what's wrong with this one.

Comment: The problem may be with your capitalization of your properties. The setters may not be able to be correctly generated from that case. I've updated my answer with that and a comment about your saving.

Comment: I thought so too then changed them to lower case... still getting the exact same error

Comment: I fixed the error, I had to put [Picture registerSubclass]; in the app delegate. Of course!

Comment: That makes sense. I'm very happy that you fixed it.